# Bokeh plot not updating with drop-down menu selection

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I'm trying to use Bokeh to create an interactive plot of sunlight (daylight) hours at various cities. I used the Bokeh gallery example "weather" for guidance, as this is my first attempt at using Bokeh. The plot works, but it doesn't update when the new city is selected from the drop down menu. Help identifying my error would be gratefully appreciated. I've created some sample data points for this simple illustration; the actual code will read an hdf file.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataRange1d, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import inferno

variables = ['sunlight_hours']#, 'Sunrise', 'Sunset']

def get_dataset(src, name, plottype):

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(t)
    df['sun'] = src[name]

    return ColumnDataSource(data=df)

def make_plot(source, title, city):
    plot = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, tools="", toolbar_location=None)
    plot.title.text = title
    plot.line(pd.to_datetime(t),sunlight[city]\
    ,line_width=2,line_color=clrs[1],legend=city)

# fixed attributes
plot.xaxis.axis_label = None
plot.yaxis.axis_label = "Sunlight [hours]"
plot.axis.axis_label_text_font_style = "bold"
#plot.x_range = DataRange1d(range_padding=0.0)
plot.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0.3

return plot

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
    new_city = city_select.value
    plot.title.text = "Sunlight data for " + new_city

    src_update = get_dataset(sunlight, new_city, plottype_select.value)
    source.data.update(src_update.data)

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

i_city = 'Toronto'
plottype = 'sunlight_hours'

# make example data
yr = 2018
sites = pd.Series(['Resolute','Edmonton','Toronto'])
provs = pd.Series(['Nunavut','Alberta','Ontario'])
sunlight = pd.DataFrame()
sunlight['Toronto']  = pd.Series( [10,11,12,13,12,11,10] )
sunlight['Edmonton'] = pd.Series( [6,8,12,14,11,7,5] )
sunlight['Resolute'] = pd.Series( [4,6,10,16,11,5,2] )

t =  pd.date_range('1-1-' + str(yr),periods=7,freq='m')
N =  len(sites)

clrs = inferno(N)

cities = {}
for i in range(0,N):
    cities.update({sites[i]: {'city': sites[i], 'province': 
provs[i],'sun_hrs':sunlight[sites[i]],}})

city_select = Select(value=i_city, title='City', options=sorted(cities.keys()))
plottype_select = Select(value=plottype, title='Plot type', options=['Sunlight']) #, 'Sunrise', 'Sunset'])

source = get_dataset(sunlight, cities[i_city]['city'], plottype)

plot = make_plot(source, "Sunlight data for ",i_city)# + cities[city]['city'])

city_select.on_change('value', update_plot)
plottype_select.on_change('value', update_plot)

controls = column(city_select, plottype_select)

curdoc().add_root(row(plot, controls))
curdoc().title = "Sunlight"
```

Comment: Instead of `source.data.update(src_update.data)` try `plot.data_source.data = src_update.data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did everything right except the way you plot the line. You used the data directly instead of the ColumnDataSource, so you are correctly updating your data source but nothing happens since it is not used by the renderer.

change

```
plot.line(pd.to_datetime(t),sunlight[city],line_width=2,line_color=clrs[1],legend=city)
```

to

```
plot.line('date','sun',line_width=2,line_color=clrs[1],legend=city,source=source)
```

Instead of passing actual arrays, pass the source and field names